# Importance of WHERE 1 in MySQL queries

Tags: mysql

When making a MySQL query with no WHERE constraints, most people use WHERE 1 in the query.  However, omitting WHERE 1 does not influence the query.  Is there a difference between the two?  Is one considered to be the best practice?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I don't think it's a matter of best practice, but people sometimes use it to make building dynamic queries a bit easier.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 1 ";
if ( somecondition ) {
   sql += "AND somefield = somevalue ";
}

if ( someothercondition ) {
   sql += "AND someotherfield = someothervalue ";
}

... etc
```

Without the `WHERE 1` in there I would need to check in each `if` block whether I needed to put in a `WHERE` or an `AND`.

Comment: @Eric is there a speed difference between `WHERE 1` and `WHERE 1 = 1` ?

Comment: @fire - no idea, you'd have you test to find out, but I would think that any decent optimizer would eliminate both expressions as being irrelevant to the query.

Answer (score 12):

It's not necessary. 99.9% of the time it just means the query was dynamically constructed and putting in `WHERE 1` leads to simpler logic for dynamic conditional clauses, meaning you can just keep adding `AND id = 3` to the end of the query and it won't break the syntax. If you don't have `WHERE 1` you have to worry about whether or not there's a `WHERE` clause and whether to prepend your condition with `AND` or not.

So it's just laziness basically.

Comment: +1 but it's not JUST laziness. It is also simpler, faster and safer

Comment: the KISS principle :)

Answer (score 9):

It's one less corner case for automated code generators and other SQL statement manipulators. By starting the filtering section with `where 1` (or `where 1 = 1`), your automated code generator can just add new filters with the `and` prefix.

Otherwise you tend to end up with code like:

```
query = "select * from tbl"
sep = " where "
foreach clause in all_clauses:
    query = query + sep + clause
    sep = "and "
```

which is not as clean as:

```
query = "select * from tbl where 1 = 1"
foreach clause in all_clauses:
    query = query + " and " + clause
```

It should make *very* little difference to any decent DBMS since the execution engine should strip out those sort of clauses before the query is executed.

Whether it's best practice or not depends on whether you'd rather have "cleaner" code in your query generators, or whether you'd rather have the company DBAs trying to track you down and beat you to death for using such silly clauses :-) Of course, if you're using MySQL, you may *be* the DBA so that may not be a problem.