# Sql Unknown column error 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run a SQL query (or multiple queries) on database of my website in phpMyadmin in the SQL tab it says

```
SELECT * FROM `shell` WHERE 1
```

SO I typed in

```
SELECT * FROM `shell` WHERE 'http://samiul.ru.cx/c0de.php';
```

but I get an error

> 1054 - "Unknown column 'http://samiul.ru.cx/c0de.php' in 'where clause'

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp

Answer (score 0):

The `shell` should be an existing table on your phpMyadmin.

After the `WHERE` statement you should place your column name that you want to filter. For example your table shell contain a column name `shell_name` with a character data type. Your sql statement should look like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM shell
WHERE shell_name like 'any_name';
```

If your not planning to filter your table you can remove the `WHERE` statement.

Leaving you only the main sql statement:

```
SELECT * FROM shell;
```

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax for a select query with where clause is:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'PARTICULAR_COLUMN_VALUE';
```

Where clause is used to filter records that satisfy a particular filter criteria.
For example, You have a table say EMP_TABLE with following structure and records,

```
EMP_NAME   |  EMP_NUMBER
NISHA      |  3322
GRASHIA    |  3696
```

If you want to fetch all columns of all records that have name as 'NISHA', then your query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM EMP_TABLE WHERE EMP_NAME = 'NISHA';
```

*Note: * *in the above query can also be expanded as SELECT EMP_NAME, EMP_NUMBER where you can explicitly mention all the column names*

If you want to fetch only particular column say emp number of employee 'NISHA' then your query can be:

```
SELECT EMP_NUMBER FROM EMP_TABLE WHERE EMP_NAME = 'NISHA';
```

For more reference on Syntax of [WHERE CLAUSE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM *table* WHERE *column* = *value*
```

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM shell WHERE webpage = 'http://samiul.ru.cx/c0de.php'
```

Or similar.

The WHERE 1 part is a little confusing.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1
```

is functionally the same as

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

Here's an explanation: [Importance of WHERE 1 in MySQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983655/importance-of-where-1-in-mysql-queries)

I've never actually had a need for it, but maybe someone has.

This is a pretty basic question. You might want to read up a little on how queries work.